# JTabbedPane tabs

Tags: java, jpanel, jtabbedpane, jpopupmenu

Alright, so I have a JTabbedPane in an application and it has several panels. Is it possible to assign a JPopupMenu to the actual tabs themselves instead of the JPanel? If it is possible, how would I do this?

Comment: I click a tab and a popup popsup?

Comment: Yes, when you right-click the tab itself, I want the JPopupMenu to appear. When I tried assigning panel.setComponentPopupMenu(popupmenu);, and went on to right-click the tab, no menu appeared, but when I right-clicked the panel itself, the menu appeared. This leads me to believe that there is some seperate thing for the tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See
http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/20810-how-can-i-add-popup-menu-tab-tabbedpane.html
for an example.

I think you would first call `setTabComponentAt([each index], [a label with a popup attached])`
then you would need to add a method in to change each of the tabs when they are clicked.